# Unresolved references of buildSrc kotlin constants after migration to gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: android, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I´m trying to migrate my android project to using gradle kotlin dsl, replacing all build.gradle files with build.gradle.kts files and using kotlin there. Already before, I used to have a kotlin file containing object elements with library and version constants (in buildSrc -> src -> main -> kotlin), like:

```
object Versions {
    const val anyLibVersion = "1.0.0"
}

object Lib {
    const val anyLib = "x:y:${Versions.anyLibVersion}"
}
```

In build.gradle files, I can access these constants without problems, but as soon as I switch them to build.gradle.kts, it cannot resolve them anymore. Any explaination for that?

Comment: Is it only an issue with android studio, or does a command line build also fail?

Comment: Is working now after reinstallation of android studio

Answer (score 6):

What you'd typically have is following in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

and then have your versions/dependencies in say `buildSrc/src/main/java/Dependencies.kt`

Comment: My buildSrc/build.gradle.kts looks exactly like that. So you are saying the mistake is that I´m using kotlin source folder instead of java source folder? I actually had that before, but thought using kotlin source folder is more appropriate. Shouldn´t it work with both?

Comment: It certainly works with `java`....haven't tried tbh using `kotlin`.....will test here in a while and see if that works (or whether for example you might need to explicitly set `sourceSets` in gradle to use)

Comment: Tried using `kotlin` here instead of `java` for folder name and looks like it's working fine.

Comment: Hm, then anything must be messed up in my project.. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Is working now after reinstallation of android studio

Answer (score 3):

Does NOT treat the buildSrc directory as an module in `settings.gradle.kts (.)`

---

## Precompiled script plugins.

Then for `apply from` in Kotlin DSL, you should use `plugins {}`

#### build.gradle.kts (X:buildSrc)

```
plugins {
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `kotlin-dsl-precompiled-script-plugins`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

---

### Precondition

#### buildSrc/src/resources/META-INF/gradlePlugins/some-package-id.properties file:

```
implementation-class=gradlePlugins.android.AndroidLibraryPlugin
```

#### buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/gradlePlugins/android/AndroidLibraryPlugin.kt

Pay attention to the package of implementation-class will be "some-package-id"

```
package gradlePlugins.android

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class AndroidLibraryPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.configurePlugins()
        project.configureAndroid()
        project.configureDependencies()
    }

}
```

---

### Consume the plugin:

Check that "some-package-id" will be the file name of `some-package-id.properties`

#### feature.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("some-package-id")
}
```

GL

- [Precompiled script plugins](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/plugins-and-apply-from-in-the-kotlin-dsl/28662/8)
- [Use buildSrc to abstract imperative logic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources)
- [Kotlin Dsl Samples](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/tree/master/samples/hello-android)
- [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54159340/5279996)
- [Commit](https://github.com/Coronel-B/Mobius-KMM/commit/8b822e58a71b4093d02b6460c7fd0ef9eec5bc64)

Comment: `Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'core-library'] was not found in any of the following sources`

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: In the `feature.gradle.kts`: `Plugin [id: 'some-package-id'] was not found in any of the following sources:`

Comment: Seems it works! I had to put the `core-library.gradle.kts` under `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/` and NOT under a `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/sub-folder/script/blah`. Although, this solution doesn't work when you have `id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")` in your `core-library.gradle.kts`. Not sure why!

Comment: Check updated answer. First, you can test only the plugin consume and then integrate dagger with their preconditions. The core-library.gradle.kts file should be outside the buildSrc module

Comment: precompiled and binary scripts are different things and you answered like it the same thing

Comment: which would be the change?

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by completely removing the android {} block, doing a Gradle sync, and then adding the code block back.