# How to migrate from Kotlin 1.2 to 1.3 with the kotlin-dsl Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

I am currently using the [*kotlin-dsl Gradle plugin 0.18.2*](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl), *Kotlin 1.2.51* and *Gradle 4.10.2* in my [Android project](https://github.com/EventFahrplan/EventFahrplan) (take a look at the temporary `project-setup` branch).
I like to migrate to *Kotlin 1.3*. However, I have difficulties in finding out which combination of version works. I raised the dependencies to their latest version:

```
// in build.gradle.kts:
id("org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl") version "1.0.4"
```

...

```
// in build.gradle:
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.10
```

As soon as I run a Gradle task it fails with the following error:

> WARNING: Unsupported Kotlin plugin version.
>   The `embedded-kotlin` and `kotlin-dsl` plugins rely on features of Kotlin `1.2.61` that might work differently than in the requested version `1.3.10`.

Is there a migration guide besides what is written in the [release notes of the *kotlin-dsl Gradle plugin*](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/releases)?

## Related

- [kotlin-dsl issue #1269: Build failed with NoSuchMethodError: KotlinPluginWrapperKt.getKotlinPluginVersion](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/1269)

Comment: I think you need to upgrade to Gradle 5.0 and kotlin-dsl 1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the migration problems was a misconfiguration of the `buildSrc` folder. I was treating it as a *module* in the *settings.gradle* file:

> include ':app', ':buildSrc', ':database', ':network'

Instead it should be treated as an *included build* as stated in the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources).
The solution given by *Paul Merlin, @eskatos* was to simply remove the `buildSrc` folder there:

> include ':app', ':database', ':network'